# Run two executables in docker

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I would like my container to launch two processes when it is run;

1. the generic "this process is runnning to keep the container awake" process (`keep_awake.sh`), and
2. `node app.js`

Is there any way to have both of these launch at the start, based in the dockerfile?

I'm thinking of some sort of abuse of bash, but don't know specifically which one yet.

Further complicating things, `keep_awake.sh` is in a directory different than `app.js`.

Comment: Just set your CMD to be `node app.js&./keep_awake.sh` surely? Why do you need a keep alive process, I'm confused, just set it to bash?

Comment: This will run `node app.js` in the background and then also run `keep_awake.sh` ? I haven't seen commands strung together like this before

Comment: It would do that, but that isn't what you really want to do as explained by Maze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never need an artificial “keep this container alive” process.  This is doubly true in the situation you’re describing, where you have a single long-running application process.

Best practice is for a Docker container to run a *single* process, and run it as a *foreground* job.  If that process ever exits, the container will exit too — and you want this.  (It’d be kind of embarrassing for your Node app to die but for you to not notice, because Docker sees that `tail -f /dev/null` is still up and running.)

In short, end your Dockerfile with

```
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

and ignore the second do-nothing process.

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me. So the idea is that containers will live and die by their process, and we use the docker hypervisor (?) to manage multiple processes?

Comment: Yes.  It’s very common to use orchestration tools like Docker Compose to run systems built out of multiple single-process containers.